# Why can I vote over the limit some days but not others?

Tags: discussion, bug, voting

Not sure if this is a bug, but sometimes I reach the maximum number of votes, which is a reasonable 40. The bug is sometimes it tells me I can vote in 1 hour after I reach the limit, sometimes it will tell me I need to wait 10 hours.

What's the reasoning behind this? Is there a bug or is something I'm not aware of?

During the 10 hour wait, at random it allows me to vote sometimes over the limit even though I'll try to vote on another, and it won't let me, stating I have to finish the wait of 10 hours. Why does it allow me at random to vote during a wait and why does the wait time vary day to day?

Example: The other day I voted 40 times and it said to wait 10 hours. Then, 3 hours later it let me vote again for no apparent reason, but on another question it gave me the message to wait 7 hours. A few days later I voted to the maximum and it said to wait just 1 hour, and let me vote at random before the hour was over.

Comment: Your vote count gets reset at 0:00 UTC. If a post that you've upvoted or downvoted get deleted within the day, you get that vote back.

Comment: @MikeM. Ahh! That makes sense! Thanks for clearing that up